# Trouble managing model ownership in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In my rails app Users and Schools can create courses, and each course has one syllabus.

in my course model:

```
belongs_to :hostable, polymorphic: true
has_one  :syllabus
```

syllabus:

```
belongs_to :course
```

school (and user):

```
has_many :courses, as: :hostable, :dependent => :destroy
```

My routes are currently set up as follows:

```
resources :users do
  resources :courses 
  member do
   get :attending, :memberships
  end
end

resources :schools do 
  resources :courses 
  member do
    put :apply, :enroll
  end
end

resources :syllabuses
```

In my syllabuses controller I have:

```
def create
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  @syllabus = @course.build_syllabus(params[:syllabus])
  if @syllabus.save
    redirect_to @course, notice: 'Syllabus was successfully created.' 
  end
end
```

my courses controller has this:

```
def show
  @course = Course.find(params[:id])
  @school = Course.find(params[:school_id])
  @title = @course.title
  unless @course.syllabus
    @syllabus = @course.build_syllabus
  end
end
```

and my course view page has

```
<%= form_for (@syllabus) do |f| %>

  <div> <%= f.label :syllabus %> </div>
  <%= f.label :name %> 
  <%= f.text_field :name %> </br>
    ....

  <%= f.submit "Save Changes" %>
<% end %>
```

but when I try to create a syllabus from a course page inside of a school I get:

"Couldn't find Course without an ID"

What am I doing wrong? How could I reconfigure my routes/models so that both Users and Schools can create a course, and then from within the course a syllabus can be created?  I tried nesting the syllabus model under the course model with javascript but I had a few problems.

Comment: The more relevant information would be your model relationships. How do you have them set up? and do they have the proper foreign keys?

Comment: @KyleC I have edited my question to include the ownership code in the models.

Comment: Try nesting syllabus in your routing routing, resources :courses do resource :syllabus . Also, check your logs to see which create action is being called

Comment: @KyleC Okay, so I went back to the nested route (someone had advised me against this, but it's the only one that works)... resources :schools do 
    resources :courses do 
      resources :syllabuses
      member do
     put :apply, :enroll
    end
  end
end

Comment: @KyleC and creating the syllabus from the course page is now working.  Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear Danny, I added it as an answer. I would appreciate if you select it as the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try nesting syllabus in your routing,

```
  resources :courses do 
     resource :syllabus
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  @school = Course.find(params[:school_id])
```

Looks suspicios to me.

Should it be

```
  @school = School.find(params[:school_id])
```

Or even more easily

```
  @school = @course.school
```